# Will Idle temperature increase when upgrading i5-8400 to i7-8700?

Tags: intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5, hyper-threading, silent-cooling

I have a passively cooled `i5-8400` which runs at about **34-40** degrees for most of the day (peaking at about **60** degrees periodically) using a Cooler Master Hyper heat sink and a single 20cm Noctura case fan that runs at minimum (noiseless) speed until it needs to shift some warm air out of the case.

The applications I use would benefit from a hyper-threading boost and rather than upgrade everything I'm thinking of swapping out the cpu for an `i7-8700`

Whilst they are both **65W TDP**, I am aware that hyperthreading, and the extra clock speed, can increase temps, but I cannot find any concrete figures of expected temp increases in a like-for-like environment.

Has anyone gone through a similar process and can tell me what they observed?

Here is a typical day for my i5-8400 system:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but can be helpful anyway: I'm not sure how feasible undervolting is on a desktop system, but you could give it a try. It could let you lower temperature a bit. Make sure to benchmark it thoroughly though to make sure it's stable with lower voltages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU-World article
[Intel Core i5-8400 vs i7-8700](http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/428/Intel_Core_i5_i5-8400_vs_Intel_Core_i7_i7-8700.html)
gives both CPUs identical thermal properties.

Both CPUs are rated for the maximum of 100°C (Digital Thermal Sensor),
from which you are very far with a maximal running temperature of only 60°.

It should be noted that the two CPUs are almost identical, as the i5 is
only an i7 that didn't make the mark on performance. Temperature is directly
related to power consumption, which is identical for both.

I don't think that you will see a big difference between the
two processors as regarding the temperature.

Comment: Like a lot of these "vs" sites, a max of 71.4 feels both very precise and very vague! i.e. I'm sure the max is not really 71.4 in all tests. To be taken with enough of a pinch of salt as to be not very useful IMO :)

Comment: The important part is they came out about the same. The figures only pertain to their setup.

Comment: Yes.  Deleted earlier comment & downvote

Answer (score 0):

I took the plunge and got a used i7-8700 off eBay...

For me at least, the temp differences are very little - in fact, if anything it's running a tiny bit cooler! - but that could be down to a number of factors beyond the CPU itself.

However increased clock speeds and hyperthreading do seem to have given me enough of a boost to be worth while - glad to be getting a little more more life out of my system before a bigger upgrade in the future.

[image]